# How would I properly implement onclick using childnodes to make a div disappear?

Tags: javascript, html, transparency, children, child-nodes

I asked a question yesterday but it was off-topic and I have worked around the code to accomplish the goal I wanted via hover but now I want each div that is clicked to become transparent. The problem that I know have is I am working in Dreamweaver instead of phpstorm and I am not sure if the command I used is valid. My html is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="category">

            <div class="content">
            </div>

            <div class="content">
            </div>

            <div class="content">
            </div>

            <div class="content">
            </div>

            <div class="content">
            </div>

        </div>

    <style>
        div { background-color: springgreen; }
        div { width: 100px; }
        div { height: 100px; }
    </style>

</body>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

and javascript:

```
/**
* Created by Mark M. on 3/28/2015.
*
*/

 var category = document.getElementById("category");
 for (var child = category.firstChild; child != null; child =    child.nextSibling) {
  if (child.nodeType == 1 && child.className == "content") {
    child.onmouseover = function() {
        this.style.width = "150px";
        this.style.height = "150px"
    };

    child.onmouseout = function() {
        this.style.width = "100px";
        this.style.height = "100px"
    };

    child.onmouseclick= function() {
        //disappear
        this.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";


    }
}}
```

Comment: Can you make fiddle for this ?

Comment: pure native JS or jquery ok?

Comment: The markup is invalid, script elements must be within the head or body. If you want to process just the *div* elements that are children of *category*, likely a selector is a better way to go.

Comment: If you are literally trying to make the div disappear without affecting layout, then `this.style.visibility = 'hidden'` will do the job. Or if you want them to not take up any room at all, use `this.style.display = 'none'`. But it would be better to apply both by adding a class value and removing the effect by removing the class.

Comment: i would like to use pure native js sorry for the late response.

Comment: I don't really mind it affecting layout i just want the div to not be visible after a click. And I am currently trying to implement some of the things people have written here but there is a lot of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

### HTML

```
<div id="category">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
var arrContent = document.querySelectorAll("#category div.content");
for(i =0; i< arrContent.length; i++){
    var child = arrContent[i];
    console.log(child)
    if (child.nodeType == 1 ) {
        child.onmouseover = function() {
            this.style.width = "150px";
            this.style.height = "150px"
        };

        child.onmouseout = function() {
            this.style.width = "100px";
            this.style.height = "100px"
        };

        child.onclick= function() {
            this.style.backgroundColor  = "transparent";
        }
    }
}`
```

### StyleSheet

```
div.content {background-color: springgreen;width: 100px;height: 100px;}
```

```js
var arrContent = document.querySelectorAll("#category div.content");
for(i =0; i< arrContent.length; i++){
var child = arrContent[i];
console.log(child)
if (child.nodeType == 1 ) {
    child.onmouseover = function() {
        this.style.width = "150px";
        this.style.height = "150px"
    };

    child.onmouseout = function() {
        this.style.width = "100px";
        this.style.height = "100px"
    };

    child.onclick= function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor  = "transparent";
    }
}
}
```

```css
div.content {background-color: springgreen;width: 100px;height: 100px;}
```

```html
<div id="category">
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this achieved the desired effect. I have been trying to comment on everyone's posts but I didn't expect such a large amount of help and I do appreciate it and try out each different way that people post it.

Answer (score 1):

This should be an elegant solution for your question. Click "Run Code Snippet" to check:

```js
var contentDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('content');

for(var i = 0; i < contentDivs.length; i++) {
    var div = contentDivs[i];
    div.onclick = function(){
        this.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```css
div {background-color: springgreen; width: 100px; height: 100px;}
```

```html
<div id="category">
    <div class="content">Content 1</div>
    <div class="content">Content 2</div>
    <div class="content">Content 3</div>
    <div class="content">Content 4</div>
    <div class="content">Content 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good solution, but it would be better to put the style declarations on one rule, not 3. ;-)

Comment: Thank for the feedback, I just copy it from the question. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using 'onmouseclick' instead of 'onclick'

how about using `document.getElementsByClassName('content')`, and `addEventListener()` instead of using the 'onX' syntax.  I believe the addEventListener is more standards compliant and should provide better browser compatibility.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

```
var content = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
console.log('content found', content);
for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i+=1){
  content[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
  });
}
```

Comment: Or maybe `var content = document.querySelectorAll('#category > div')`. ;-)

Comment: yes, I was just about to add the querySelectorAll suggestion. You beat me to it :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: or may be `var content = document.querySelectorAll('#category > div.content')` :P

Comment: I'd probably use event delegation and put a single listener on the *content*.

Comment: I would agree with using event delegation http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate if we're talking about really, really long lists of .content items.  For most cases I doubt it would ever make any practical difference :)

Comment: That said, if he is adding and removing .content items with ajax, event delegation is absolutely the right approach.  While jquery is overused in many places, it has a really nice api for that which makes it a lot easier to manage the selectors.